# Select Time Data

Tags: r, sorting, date, select, as.date

I only want to select the data between 2015-1 and 2018-1.

```
usefuldata1 <-usefuldata[usefuldata$zeit > "2014 - 12",]

usefuldata2 <-usefuldata1[usefuldata1$zeit < "2018-2",]
```

Bigger than 2014 works. However, smaller than 2018 does not.
I get the same number as before.

My data looks as follows:

```
x <- sample(letters, size = 30, replace = T)
y <- paste(sample(2010:2020, size = 30, replace = T),
           sample(1:12, size = 30, replace = T), sep = "-")

df <- data.frame(name = x, date = y)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a very userfull type in R called Date, by experience about 90% of all problems about dates can be solved by that.

```
   see: ?as.Date for help
```

In your case, the first thing to do is format **y** as a Date type adding the days.

```
   x <- sample(letters, size = 30, replace = T)
   y <- paste(sample(2010:2020, size = 30, replace = T),
       sample(1:12, size = 30, replace = T),
       "01", sep = "-") # <- this is the day (01) for all.
```

Then we have to format it as a *Date* type.

```
   y = as.Date(y, format = "%Y-%m-%d") # year complete (%Y), month (%m) and day (%d)
   df <- data.frame(name = x, date = y)
```

And subset them.

```
    dateIndex = which(y > "2014-12-31" & y < "2018-01-01")
    subset_df = df[dateIndex,]
```

I hope this helps you.